# Highlight specific points (based on a condition) in a scatter plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn

I have an numpy array, which I Convert to a dataframe to visualize it in matplotlib.pytplot:

```
x = np.array([[10,10,1], [10,20,0], [10,3,0]])
df = pd.DataFrame(x, columns=["x", "y", "z"])
```

If i plot a scatter plot based on the column z as color, i get the following output(note that I am using different values):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df["val"] = df['z'].apply(lambda x: "red" if x==1 else "blue")
ax.scatter(x=df["x"], y=df["y"], c=df["val"], s=100)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(15, 10)
plt.plot()
```

[image]

So all the red points are not shown in the plot. How can I highlight them?

If I run seaborn it is working, but is there a way in matplotlib:

```
import seaborn as sns
sns.lmplot('x', 'y', data =df, hue='z', fit_reg=False)
fig = plt.gcf()
fig.set_size_inches(15, 10)
plt.show()
```

[image]

The similar question: [How can I highlight a dot in a cloud of dots with Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59090592/how-can-i-highlight-a-dot-in-a-cloud-of-dots-with-matplotlib)
only make the dots bigger, but does not put them in front. This is then missleading somehow.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I highlight a dot in a cloud of dots with Matplotlib?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59090592/how-can-i-highlight-a-dot-in-a-cloud-of-dots-with-matplotlib)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don't you just plot them separately so you can set different parameters? On top of that, if you plot the red points after, they will be on top of the blue ones.

Here's an example based on yours:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

x = np.array([np.random.rand(2000), np.random.rand(2000), np.random.rand(2000)])
df = pd.DataFrame(np.transpose(x), columns=["x", "y", "z"])

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
df["val"] = df['z'].apply(lambda x: "red" if x>.9 else "blue")

not_red_df = df.loc[df['val'] != 'red']
red_df = df.loc[df['val'] == 'red']

ax.scatter(x=not_red_df["x"], y=not_red_df["y"], c=not_red_df["val"], s=100)
ax.scatter(x=red_df["x"], y=red_df["y"], c=red_df["val"], s=100)

fig = plt.gcf()
plt.plot()
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can sort your data so that the foreground points are drawn last as shown in the lower plot of the following example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(pd.np.random.rand(1000,3), columns=["x", "y", "z"])
df.z = df.z.add(.1).astype(int)
df["val"] = df['z'].apply(lambda x: "red" if x==1 else "blue")

df1 = df.sort_values('z')

fig, ax = plt.subplots(2)
ax[0].scatter(x=df["x"], y=df["y"], c=df["val"], s=100)
ax[1].scatter(x=df1["x"], y=df1["y"], c=df1["val"], s=100)
```

[image]